# Hierarchical select as radio buttons and checkboxes

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, forms

I have a need to display a hierarchical select of a vocabulary as a series of radio buttons representing the top-level terms.  When the user selects one of the radio buttons, the child taxonomy terms should be displayed below as checkboxes.

Do I need to build a custom AHAH form, or can I look at form altering the default hierarchical select widget?

Answer (score 1):

For drupal 6 you may want to check out the module https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields which basically lets you control which form elements depend on other form elements. It also has a handy GUI for doing this.

FYI drupal 7 has completely changed the game here and has implemented 'states api' - here is an example of what can easily be achieved - http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example--form_example_states.inc/function/form_example_states_form/7

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do something like that using [Taxonomy Super Select (TSS)](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_super_select) for Drupal 6. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... seamlessly overrides the select box generated by the taxonomy module and renders the terms based on if you are allowing multiple selections or not.
>
> **Features**:
>
> - Multiple selection vocabularies show as checkboxes.
> - Single selection terms display as radio buttons.
> - Parent terms display as nested fieldsets
> - Option to display parented terms as form items
> - Ability to control which content types TSS will apply to
> - Works with all hierarchy configurations
> - Free tagging vocabularies are now supported.